# How to improve the question about the design of the controller in lunar lander?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, editing

[Criticism on the UX of the control panel of the lunar module](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/12610/12270)

I'm not new to SE, but new to here. This question is closed as unclear, and well, I agree with that. The question comes from my poor memory, so although I have tried my best, it cannot contain enough information to make it clearer (it even couldn't help me google by myself). The answers provide good information, but I'm looking for an answer that specifies on the UX of the controller. Therefore I want to improve this to reopen the question.

One more thing. After the edit, the title is less clear than it used to be. Because the editor is PearsonArtPhoto, I think I have an ignorance. Can you explain me why?

Comment: Can you specify what you want to know about the controls?

Comment: @kimholder I'm looking for an answer that specifies on the UX of the controller

Comment: Russell's answer says a fair bit about that, focusing on how the controls were actually used to land and what that was like. So what is missing? More commentary from the astronauts on what it was like? More information on the numberpad and readout (which don't really seem to have been used during the landing procedure you are asking about)?

Comment: @kimholder thanks for the suggestion. I'm looking for the criticism on the UX of the controller. I have added this on the question.

Comment: First, I don't think UX is a common term within the space exploration field, I recommend at least expanding it to 'user experience'. Second, you can't assume based on a vague memory of one source whose reliability is unknown that there was, in fact, criticism of the design of the controls by the Apollo astronauts. If you haven't been able to find such material, and nobody so far has had a reference for such statements, at the least that opinion was uncommon and not strongly felt. This could be a reason why it is deemed unclear - the matter wasn't the way you recall it being reported.

Comment: I have expanded the term. I'm quite sure about the criticism, since I have an image of the panel in my memory. I just cannot extract it out. But yeah, I agree that if the question based solely on my memory, chance that it won't be clear in any way.